# Is it possible to increase the size of UI text in Empire: Total War?

Tags: empire-total-war

When playing Empire Total War at the highest resolution on my laptop, the text on most UI elements (most of the menus, notices, mouseover text etc) is too small to read easily. Currently I have to turn down the resolution to solve this, which is not an ideal solution. Is there some sort of large text option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mod increases text size:

http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?t=252620